# With pytest, how to correctly mock a function of an external module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

## Problem description

I am using the ibis framework and I would like to mock it for some unit tests.

There are two functions un ibis that I want to mock:

```
import ibis
ibis.impala.connect
```

and

```
ibis.hdfs_connect
```

These functions are used inside a custom class:

```
class Impala(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    """An Impala wrapper to handle impala connexion et specific actions
    This class is a thread safe singleton thus can be used in multi threads
    programs
    """

    def __init__(self, user: str = os.environ.get('HDFS_WRITER_LOGIN'),
                 password: str = os.environ.get('HDFS_WRITER_PWD')) -> None:
        """Initiate impala connexion

        Parameters
        ----------
        user : str, optional
            User name, by default os.environ['HDFS_WRITER_LOGIN']
        password : str, optional
            User password, by default os.environ['HDFS_WRITER_PWD']
        """

        if (type(user) is not str
                or type(password) is not str):
            raise TypeError("type of user or password is not str")

        if (len(user) < 1
                or len(password) < 1):
            raise ValueError("Username or passwordd too short")

        self.hdfs = ibis.hdfs_connect(
            host=os.environ['HDFS_IP'], port=os.environ['HDFS_PORT'])
        try:
            self.impala = ibis.impala \
                .connect(host=os.environ['IMPALA_IP'],
                         port=int(os.environ['IMPALA_PORT']),
                         hdfs_client=self.hdfs,
                         user=user, password=password, auth_mechanism='PLAIN')

            signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.__close)
            atexit.register(self.__close)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.impala = None
```

Based on [this documentation](https://changhsinlee.com/pytest-mock/), I ended with this for my test file for the mock (this test is WIP, this is why it does not do much):

```
import pytest

from .impala import Impala
@pytest.mark.hadoopimpala
class TestImpala:
    def test_impala_type(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch(
            'ibis.hdfs_connect',
            lambda: True
        )
        mocker.patch(
            'ibis.impala.connect',
            lambda: False
        )
        assert Impala().get() is not None
```

However, when running pytest on that test file, I have the following error:

> \anaconda\lib\site-packages\ibis\**init**.py'> does not have the
> attribute 'hdfs_connect'

## Question

In my case, how can I properly mock these two functions for my unit tests ?

## Edit 1

It seems that my local machine does not have the same version of ibis that our cluster uses.

My local is `1.4.0` while the cluster is `0.12.0`. Investigating in this direction.

Comment: Shouldn't `ibis.hdfs_connect` be `ibis.impala.hdfs_connect`? I've never used the library, but when I pip install it, that's what I'm able to import.

Comment: Well. Now I am very confused. What you say is true, but when I try `ibis.hdfs_connect`, it actually works and return a `ibis.filesystems.WebHDFS` object. Moreover, we have been using this since the beginning without any issue. @FMc

Comment: @FMc moreover, `ibis.impala.hdfs_connect`  throws `module 'ibis.impala.api' has no attribute 'hdfs_connect'`